# JSON Response returning numbers, not actual data

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

I'm working on a swift app that interacts with the Shopify API. When I view the API endpoint in a browser, I see the actual data. Whenever I make the same request with Swift (using Alamofire to make HTTP requests), nothing but a series of numbers are returned like this:

```
  7b226375 73746f6d 5f636f6c 6c656374 696f6e73 223a5b7b 22626f64 795f6874 6d6c223a 22222c22 68616e64 6c65223a 22616363 6573736f 72696573 222c2269 64223a34 37303136 30322c22 7075626c 69736865 645f6174 223a2232 3031332d 31312d30 38543135 3a32393a 30302d30 383a3030 222c2270 75626c69 73686564 5f73636f 7065223a 22676c6f 62616c22 2c22736f 72745f6f 72646572 223a226d 616e7561 6c222c22 74656d70 6c617465 5f737566 66697822 3a22222c 22746974 6c65223a 22416363 6573736f 72696573 222c2275 70646174 65645f61 74223a22 32303135 2d30372d 30335430 383a3332 3a30332d 30373a30 30227d2c 7b22626f 64795f68 746d6c22 3a22222c 2268616e 646c6522 3a226265 616e6965 73222c22 6964223a 31313238 39383331 2c227075 626c6973 6865645f 6174223a 22323031 332d3131 2d303854 31353a32 343a3030 2d30383a 3030222c 22707562 6c697368 65645f73 636f7065 223a2267 6c6f6261 6c222c22 736f7274 5f6f7264 6572223a 226d616e 75616c22 2c227465 6d706c61 74655f73 75666669 78223a22 222c2274
```

The data on this endpoint looks like this in a browser:

```
{"custom_collections":[{"body_html":"","handle":"accessories","id":4701602,"published_at":"2013-11-08T15:29:00-08:00","published_scope":"global","sort_order":"manual","template_suffix":"","title":"Accessories","updated_at":"2015-07-03T08:32:03-07:00"},
```

Comment: Show us your swift code. I feel like you're not passing all required headers. Also which API call is this?

Comment: http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the "series of numbers" is the NSData (byte) representation of the JSON string

```
7b is {
22 is "
63 is c
```

etc.

you can use NSJSONSerialization to convert it to Dictionary/Array structures or NSString(data : NSData) to get the string representation

Comment: How do I get the data that's returned in the browser and not this?

Comment: see the edited post. It depends what kind of type you need

Answer (score 1):

Per the [README](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire): to get JSON data from Alamofire, use the `responseJSON` method:

```
Alamofire.request(...)
         .responseJSON() { request, response, jsonData, error in
              println("json data: \(jsonData)")
         }
```

Comment: @mattt: Feeling lucky? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31216242/alamofire-playground-example-breaks-with-https-url-in-version-1-2-1 ;-)